# MongoDB Go Driver's UnmarshalBSONValue - can I set a pointer struct field to nil if value is a BSON null (without omitempty)?

Tags: mongodb, bson, mongo-go, mongo-go-driver

Consider my custom string-type `Id` which marshals/unmarshals to/from a BSON ObjectId (we abstract-away the underlying BSON at our data layer; our services are agnostic to our storage):

```golang
package id

import (
    "fmt"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/bsontype"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/bsonx/bsoncore"
)

type Id string

func (id *Id) MarshalBSONValue() (bsontype.Type, []byte, error) {
    if id == nil {
        return bsontype.Null, nil, nil
    }
    oid, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(string(*id))
    if err != nil {
        return 0, nil, fmt.Errorf("cannot marshal Id value %q to BSON ObjectId: %v", *id, err)
    }
    return bsontype.ObjectID, bsoncore.AppendObjectID(nil, oid), nil
}

func (id *Id) UnmarshalBSONValue(t bsontype.Type, data []byte) error {
    if t == bsontype.Null {
        return nil
    }
    if t != bsontype.ObjectID {
        return fmt.Errorf("cannot unmarshal non-ObjectId BSON type %q to Id", t)
    }
    oid, ok := bsoncore.Value{Type: t, Data: data}.ObjectIDOK()
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("invalid BSON ObjectId data while unmarshalling Id, data=%v", data)
    }
    *id = Id(oid.Hex())
    return nil
}
```

Now, consider a struct `X` which has `Id` and `*Id` fields, one of which does not have "omitempty":

```golang
type X struct {
    Id  Id  `bson:"id,omitempty"`
    Id2 *Id `bson:"id2,omitempty"`
    Id3 *Id `bson:"id3"`
}
```

As expected, marshalling a zero-value, `x := &X{}`, results in the serialized BSON `{id3: null}`.

However, unmarshalling that serialized BSON, `{id3: null}`, into `X` results with `Id3` being set as a pointer to an empty `Id`. When unmarshalling into pointer fields, is there a way to set `Id3` to `nil`? Can that be done as a `bson.ValueUnmarshaller`? Or can this only be done in structs with custom `UnmarshalBSON` functions?

[Playground example](https://go.dev/play/p/qcc7mQo3VUO)